# PHP Variable Variable inside []'s

Tags: php

Thanks for the help below, however, I'm still having some problems, I'll try and explain further:

I have a variable as follows:

```
$value['questions'];
```

Now, I need to do a check in a loop, so I have this piece of code in the loop:

```
if($results[$value['questions']]==4){blah blah blah};
```

but the problem I am having is that the value of `$value['questions']` is q1 but I need the q1 to be a string `(i.e. inside quotes '')` in the $results section of the code, so the $results element should look like this...

```
if($results['q1']==4){blah blah blah};
```

currently it looks like this

```
if($results[q1]==4){blah blah blah};
```

Make sense?

Thanks again for the help.

Hi all,

I hope there is a simple solution!

I have a variable:

```
$results['q1'];
```

Is it possible to have the 'q1' element as a variable, something like this:

```
$results['$i[question]'];
```

Have not been able to find a solution on Google and researching the PHP manuals...

Anyone got a suggestion/ solution?

Thanks,

Homer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, **it is possible to use a variable as indice**, when accessing an array element.

As an example, consider this portion of code :

```
$results = array(
    'a' => 'sentence a', 
    'b' => 'hello !', 
);

$indice = 'a';
echo $results[$indice];
```

Which will give the following output :

```
sentence a
```

Here, `$indice` is a quite simple variable, but you could have used whatever you wanted between the `[` and `]`, like, for instance :

- functions : `$results[ my_function($parameter) ]`
- array element : `$result[ $my_array['indice'] ]`

  - Which seems to be what you want to do ?
- object property : `$result[ $obj->data ]`
- ...

Basically, you can use pretty much whatever you want there -- as long as it evaluates to a scalar value *(i.e. a single integer, string)*

In your specific case, you could have `$results` declared a bit like this :

```
$results = array(
    'q1' => 'first question', 
    'q2' => 'second question', 
);
```

And `$i` would be declared this way :

```
$i = array(
    'question' => 'q1'
);
```

Which means that `$i['question']` would be `'q1'`, and that the following portion of code :

```
echo $results[ $i['question'] ];
```

Would get you this output :

```
first question
```

---

**Edit :** To answer the specific words you used in the title of your question, you could also use what's called **[variable variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)** in PHP :

```
$variable = 'a';
$indice = 'variable';
echo $results[ $$indice ];
```

Here :

- `$indice` is `'variable'`
- and `$$indice` is `'a'`
- which means you'll get the same output as before

And, of course, don't forget to read the [**Arrays**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) section of the PHP manual.

The *[Why is $foo[bar] wrong?](http://v)* paragraph could be of interest, especially, considering the example you firt posted.

---

**Edit after the edit of the OP :**

If `$value['questions']` is `'q1'`, then, the two following portions of code :

```
if($results[$value['questions']]==4){blah blah blah}
```

and

```
if($results['q1']==4){blah blah blah}
```

should do exactly the same thing : with `$results[$value['questions']]`, the `$value['questions']` part will be evaluated (to `'q1'`) before the rest of the expression, and that one will be the same as `$results['q1']`.

As an example, the following portion of code :

```
$results = array(
    'q1' => 4, 
    'q2' => 6, 
);
$value = array('questions' => 'q1');

if($results[$value['questions']]==4) {
    echo "4";
}
```

Outputs `4`.

Comment: @Pascal - thanks for the heads up - don't know if you can then answer the question above?

Comment: @Homer : I've edited my answer with an example that's closer to your specific situation ; hope this helps :-)

Comment: @Pascal - nearly answered but not quite - the value of $value['questions' is q1 NOT 'q1' but the $results section of the code  currently shows $results[q1] and NOT $results['q1'] and therefore won't work.  Any further help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the value of `$value['questions']` is `q1`, then is it a string *(no other PHP type can contain this)* ;;; `'q1'` is just the way people write it, to indicate it's a string, as PHP expects strings to be enclosed in quotes, when written in PHP code. ;;;; if `$a` contains the value `q1`, then `$results[$a]` will be exactly the same as `$results['q1']`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification - then it would seen my check function maybe flawed :(

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
$results[$i['question']];
```

This will first access the array `$i` to get the **value** corresponding to the **key** `'question'`. That value will be used as the key into the array `$results`.

Your way: `$results['$i[question]'];`
is actually trying to get the value corresponding to the key `'$i[question]'` in the array `$results`. Since the key is in single quote, variable interpolation does **not** happen and the entire string is treated literally.

Alternatively you can also do:

```
   $results["$i[question]"]; // using double quotes also works.
```

Example:

```
$arr1 = array('php' => 'zend', 'java' => 'oracle');
$arr2 = array('p' => 'php', 'j' => 'java');

echo $arr1[$arr2['p']]; // prints zend.
echo $arr1["$arr2[p]"]; // prints zend.
```

Comment: @Uni - thanks - I am trying to bring back the value corresponding to the key, as you state in your first para - I need to use this as a string though - see updated question.

Comment: @Hormer: It will be treated as the string by default. You need to do any additional thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$result['q1'];

// is equivalent to

$index = 'q1';
$result[ $index ];
```

Now `$index` can be as complex as you want it to be. For example something like this is also possible:

```
$result[ 'q' . round( $someArray[$i] / 2 ) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

**CODE**

```
<?php

$results = array(
    'q1' => 'This is a result called q1.',
    'q2' => 'So, can you access this?',
    '$i[question]' => 'This is a result called $i[question]',
);

$i = array(
    'question' => 'q2',
    'answer'   => 'Yes.'
);

echo '<pre>';
echo $results['q1'] . "\n";              // Using Array's is easy -
echo $results['$i[question]'] . "\n";    // all you gotta do is make sure
echo $results[$i['question']] . "\n";    // that you understand how
echo $i['answer'];                       // the keys work.

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
This is a result called q1.
This is a result called $i[question]
So, can you access this?
Yes.
```

Comment: Thanks Allyn, I'm getting there but slowly, I've updated my questions, any further suggestions?